# If b and d are positive real numbers, then prove that $\frac{b+d}{2}>(bd)^{\frac 12}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove the following statement:

If $b$ and $d$ are positive real numbers, then $\frac{b+d}{2}\geq(bd)^{\frac 12}$.

Thank you.

Comment: $(b-d)^2 \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Take b=d and you'll end up wiht b>b which is clearly wrong, so the sign should be > instead of $\ge$

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt b-\sqrt d)^2\geq 0$$
$$b-2\sqrt{bd}+d\geq 0$$
$$b+d\geq2\sqrt{bd}$$
$$\frac{b+d}{2}\geq\sqrt{bd}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that uses the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality. The hint is to use $0\leq (b-d)^2 = (b+d)^2 - 4bd$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\begin{multline}(b-d)^2\geq 0 \implies (b^2-2bd+d^2)\geq 0 \implies (b^2+2bd+d^2)\geq 4bd \implies \\ \implies b+d\geq 2\sqrt{bd} \implies \frac{b+d}{2}\geq \sqrt{bd}.\end{multline}$$